# Relative path (image) resolved incorrectly in external resource (SVG) of external resource (JSON)

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg, relative-path

### The problem

I am making an (experimental) web app, where the URL to an external file is given in the actual URL, like so:

`https://example.com/path1/app.html#https://otherdomain.com/path2/data.json`

So when the page is opened, the external file (in this example `data.json`) is fetched and evaluated. So far so good.

Now `data.json` contains HTML markup, which includes an inline SVG image, which in turn features external images. In other words, in the SVG I have an `<image>` with an `xlink:href` (or `href`) attribute that is a *relative* path to an image, supposed to be stored in `https://otherdomain.com/path2/` (i.e. where the JSON file is).

**The problem is** that when the SVG file is embedded, the relative paths of external resources with be resolved based on the URL of the web page, i.e. `https://example.com/path1/`, which results in 404 errors for the `<image>`s in the SVG. The question is now how to deal with this in the best or most proper way.

### Current workaround

Basically, as current workaround I am manipulating the `href` attribute of each `<image>` in the SVG before the SVG is added to the DOM. This works well, for a workaround.

However, I have to take some less straightforward methods of parsing the SVG, to avoid eager loading of images before the paths have been fixed. (The browser already attempts fetching, when `imageElement.src` is getting changed.) So something like `parentElement.innerHTML = svgText` does not work as I hoped.

I have tried a couple of things to avoid eager loading of images. From those that worked, almost all had the new problem that the added HTML element did not pick up any CSS styles for some reason unknown to me. As workaround-within-the-workaround (yeah I know) I am doing `parentElement.innerHTML = svgElement.outerHTML`, which feels really bad, but at least works. I am sure there is a better way yet to be discovered.

### Other notes

In summary a relative path within an external resource, loaded from an external resource, is not resolved correctly. Which is not a surprise, but I wonder how to go about it.

- I would like to keep the SVG in the JSON, i.e. to be added to the DOM. (I assume loading the SVG as (HTML) `<img>` with absolute path would help.)
- I want to avoid embedding images as binary blobs in the SVG.
- Making the `href` of SVG `<image>`s an absolute path during SVG creation would probably work, but seems like a pain to create and maintain in my case.
- Going with the workaround and rewriting `href` attributes within the SVG seems cumbersome and slightly wrong, but it works. However, it should be optimised.

I wished there would be some way where I can specify explicitly what the base path is to which relative paths are added, when it comes to loading of external resources. But I wonder whether something in the overall approach needs to change here. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: use a base tag? use a custom attribute? If you're not picking up the right styles maybe you're not creating the elements in the right namespace. All of this is difficult to diagnose without a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If the path is relative the browser will concatenate the URL of the webpage to it automatically. So make sure to get everything with a full path i.e "https://example.com/images/image_1"